# Story Identification: Book about a man traveling in three worlds on an adventure

Tags: story-identification, books

Read this book about 20+ years ago:

Not sure what genre, perhaps YA fantasy, even though it was about a middle-aged and childless gentleman who lived alone and loved reading children's stories. From memory, he maintained a nursery in his house and longed to be a father.

He somehow embarks on an adventure across three different worlds inhabited by the characters he reads about. One of them was based on Winnie the Pooh and the Hundred Acre Wood, while another was a land populated by giants. I've never been able to recall this book's title.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The "three different worlds" part rings a bell.  Any distinction about the three worlds?  Why three worlds?  Was there some sort of quest?

Comment: I'm really not sure why it was just three worlds... Or how and why the protagonist even sets out on his adventure.

I just recall him wandering into the Hundred Acre Wood and meeting Winnie the Pooh, Tigger, and the others. 

I have a feeling he then moves into a more fantastical setting involving magic, but my other recollections are vague. I think giants/monsters were present at one point, maybe with a town under siege by them? For some reason, Cornwall seems to be a familiar location name when I try and remember details of this story...